# Why does the StackExchangeRedis NHibernate Second Level Cache require a locking mechanism?

Tags: nhibernate, stackexchange.redis, second-level-cache

This provider has a locking mechanism, but other related providers (most notably [NHibernate.Caches.CoreDistributedCache.Redis](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate-Caches/tree/master/CoreDistributedCache/NHibernate.Caches.CoreDistributedCache.Redis)) have no such mechanism.

Is there a specific use case of this provider that requires this?

I'm ideally looking to make use of Redis as a 2LC for NHibernate, but the locking support in this provider has serious performance implications for our application, so I'm wondering if I can simply override this behavior to make it a no-op if it's not important for our usage of it.